# CQ-Getting date and time as raw strings using xtype="datetime"

Tags: java, aem

I am pretty new to CQ and I am adding a new field to an existing form. 
I want to accept a date and time from the component dialog as strings. If I use xtype="datefield" and xtype="timefield" separately, I can get the date and time as strings just the way I need it. But, the UI looks bad and non-intiutive with two separate fields placed one below the other.

dialog.xml:

```
<startDate
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Event Start Date"
    fieldDescription="Select a date "
    emptyText="Event start date "
    name="./startDate"
    format="d/m/Y"
    xtype="datefield" />
<startTime
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Event Start Time"
    fieldDescription="Select a time "
    emptyText="Event start time "
    name="./startTime"
    xtype="timefield" />
```

Java code in controller:

```
@Property(path = "startDate")
private String startDate;

@Property(path = "startTime")
private String startTime;
```

If I use xtype="datetime", the UI looks the way I like but the value is converted to UTC into a Date field.

dialog.xml

```
<startDateTime
   jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
   fieldLabel="Start Date &amp; Time"
   name="./startDateTime"
   dateFormat="d/m/Y"
   xtype="datetime"/>
```

Java code in controller:

```
@Property(path = "startDateTime")
private Date startDateTime;
```

This is of no use to me as I need the date and time as raw strings, the way they were entered. The need for obtaining date & time as strings is driven by the requirement which states 'The author should be able to enter a specific date and time that an event starts and ends at a particular city. So the author enters the date, time and timezone of the event'. I need to display the date&time on the page and also add a calendar link. The valueAsString option looked promising but does not give me date and time as strings. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE:**
Using the xtype="compositefield" suggested by @Sharath, I can achieve the desired UI but unfortunately the values are retained when I edit the component. The values are entered accurately and I can display it on the screen but when the component is edited, the fields go back to being empty. There were no changes in the java file.

Updated dialog.xml:

```
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <eStart jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            xtype="compositefield"
            fieldLabel="Start"
            fieldDescription="Select event start date &amp; time">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <startDate
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                emptyText="Event start date "
                name="./startDate"
                format="d/m/Y"
                xtype="datefield"
                width="240"/>
            <startTime
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                emptyText="Event start time "
                name="./startTime"
                xtype="timefield"
                width="180"/>
        </items>
    </eStart>
     *
     *
</items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this :

1) Use a [compositefield](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.CompositeField) and place the date and time fields within it. Compositefield displays the widgets within it in a horizontal row. With this method the fields will be displayed like the datetime xtype but still store values independently as strings.

2) Use datetime xtype and read the value as String instead of Date and split the value by "T". (I'd go with 1)

I think i was wrong about the composite field, it displays and stores the value but does not read back the values next time (inspite of  the get request to the node returning those values )

Here's an alternative

```
{
  xtype:"panel",
  border:false,
  layout:"hbox",
  jcr:  primaryType:"cq:Widget",
  items:{
    jcr:    primaryType:"cq:WidgetCollection",
    label:{
      flex:"30",
      xtype:"label",
      jcr:      primaryType:"cq:Widget",
      text:"Date Time"
    },
    datefield:{
      flex:"40",
      xtype:"datefield",
      name:"./date",
      jcr:      primaryType:"cq:Widget"
    },
    timefield:{
      flex:"30",
      xtype:"timefield",
      name:"./time",
      jcr:      primaryType:"cq:Widget"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The option 1) is exactly what I need. Thank you. I searched for something like that and found many others but not this. I had tried the option 2) in my first attempt but CQ was throwing exception 'could not parse/IllegalArgument'(don't remember the exact type) which made me to post the question. CQ was not allowing to use a String type and datetime combo and valueAsString did not help either.

Comment: Unfortunately, the compositefield is not loading the values in the fields while editing the component.

Comment: can you add the updated dialog.xml , make sure that the name property is on individual fields and not on the composite field

Comment: Sorry, I was moved around projects and finally got this task again. @Sharath, I did name the fields individually and nothing on the compositefield, but no luck. Please find my update on the question.

Comment: @VijayKalidindi , there is an alternative called hbox layout , give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I think datetime is the easier option. With the Date object you can then use  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to get the date in the required format.
You can use the same formatting in the dialog as well as the output.

Another advantage is that you could filter and sort nodes of this type by Date, as opposed to save the values as Strings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought stating the requirement might not be required but now realize that it helps understand the question better(edited the question). The problem using Date object is that CQ is converting the date&time to the server UTC times and I lose track of the actual date&time that author had set unless I get the author timezone somehow (which I felt is not a better solution than accepting strings).